# Javascript object color change dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, collision-detection, euclidean-distance

Here's the code to change color of balls to red when two balls collide.I'm almost there but  but i don't seem to find the fault because one ball is not changing the color.Please help me out guys!!

```
 //generate a random number within a range
    function randomXToY(minVal,maxVal,floatVal)
    {
      var randVal = minVal+(Math.random()*(maxVal-minVal));
      return typeof floatVal=='undefined'?Math.round(randVal):randVal.toFixed(floatVal);
    }

    // The Ball class
    Ball = (function() {

      // constructor
      function Ball(x,y,radius,color){
        this.center = {x:x, y:y};  
        this.radius = radius;               
        this.color = color;
        this.dx = 2;               
        this.dy = 2;        
        this.boundaryHeight = $('#ground').height();
        this.boundaryWidth = $('#ground').width();

        this.dom  = $('<p class="circle"></p>').appendTo('#ground');

        // the rectange div a circle
        this.dom.width(radius*2);
        this.dom.height(radius*2);
        this.dom.css({'border-radius':radius,background:color});

        this.placeAtCenter(x,y);         
      }

      // Place the ball at center x, y
      Ball.prototype.placeAtCenter = function(x,y){
        this.dom.css({top: Math.round(y- this.radius), left: Math.round(x - this.radius)});
        this.center.x = Math.round(x);        
        this.center.y = Math.round(y);             
      };

      Ball.prototype.setColor = function(color) {
        if(color) {
          this.dom.css('background',color);
        } else {
          this.dom.css('background',this.color);
        }           
      };

      // move and bounce the ball
      Ball.prototype.move = function(){
        var diameter = this.radius * 2;                                               
        var radius = this.radius;  
        if (this.center.x - radius < 0 || this.center.x + radius > this.boundaryWidth ) {
          this.dx = -this.dx;
        }
        if (this.center.y - radius < 0 || this.center.y  + radius > this.boundaryHeight ) {
          this.dy = -this.dy;
        }
        this.placeAtCenter(this.center.x + this.dx ,this.center.y +this.dy);

      };



      return Ball;
    })();

    var number_of_balls = 5;
    var  balls = [];   
      var x; 
    var y;
    $('document').ready(function(){
      for (i = 0; i < number_of_balls; i++) { 
        var boundaryHeight = $('#ground').height();
        var boundaryWidth = $('#ground').width();
         y = randomXToY(30,boundaryHeight - 50);
         x = randomXToY(30,boundaryWidth - 50);
        var radius = randomXToY(15,30);
        balls.push(new Ball(x,y,radius, '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16))); 
      }
      loop(); 
      check();

    });

    check = function(){
      for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++){

      for(var j=0;j<balls.length;j++){
        if (i!=j) {
          if (Math.pow(balls[j].center.x - balls[i].center.x, 2) + Math.pow(balls[j].center.y - balls[i].center.y, 2) <= Math.pow(balls[i].radius + balls[j].radius, 2)) {
            console.log(true);
            balls[j].setColor('red');
            balls[i].setColor('red');
          } else {
            balls[j].setColor(balls[j].color);

          } 
        }

     }}

       setTimeout(check,8);  
    };

    loop = function(){
      for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++){
        balls[i].move();
      }

      setTimeout(loop, 8);    
    };
```

Here's the jsbin :  http://jsbin.com/imofat/790/edit

Comment: @RobinMaben I am on 21.0.1180.89 and it does not work for some of the balls sometimes. Try changing to more balls and test again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The balls are all colliding; the formula for the collision is correct, i.e.:

```
(dx * dx) + (dy * dy) <= sum of the circles' radii
```

The problem, is that sometimes the screen is not updated to reflect the new color, due to the single-threaded nature of JavaScript, and the `else` part of the `if` that resets the color.

For example, when `ball[0]` collides with `ball[1]`, you set `ball[0]`'s color to `red` in the `if`, which is **OK**. However, if `ball[0]` ***does not*** collide with `ball[2]` in the next iteration of the inner loop (`j=2`), for example, it will ***reset*** `ball[0]`'s color back to its original color, and since the screen will only be rendered ***after*** the loop is over (again, due to the single-threaded nature of JavaScript), you never see the `red` color in this situation.

So, you have two options. **1)** Either **[`break`](http://jsbin.com/imofat/829/edit)** it out of the *inner* loop when a collision occurs (if you don't need to test every other collision); **2)** Mark which balls have already collided, and only reset the colors of those who have never collided before in the loop, using an `Array`, for example:

```
var collisions = [];
for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < balls.length; j++) {
    if (i!=j) {
      if (Math.pow(balls[j].center.x - balls[i].center.x, 2) + Math.pow(balls[j].center.y - balls[i].center.y, 2) <= Math.pow(balls[i].radius + balls[j].radius, 2)) {
        collisions[i] = true;
        balls[i].setColor('red');
      } else {
        if (!collisions[i]) {
          balls[i].setColor(balls[i].color);
        }
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Also, the second loop could be simplified to start from `i + 1` instead of `0`. This way, you not only reduce the number of collision tests, but also remove the `i != j` test.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/imofat/820/edit)**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the red to persist after a collision occurs, you need to set the color of the ball:

```
Ball.prototype.setColor = function(color) {        
    if(color) {
      this.color = color;  // The ball's color is now this value. 
      this.dom.css('background',color);
    } else {
      this.dom.css('background',this.color); // so when this is called, the ball will be that color going forward.
    }           
};
```

Comment: Why not just remove the else in the nested `for` loops of `check()`? Works too.